# SSH Ubuntu server not replying to mac client

Tags: server, ssh, mac, connection, authentication

I'm trying to connect to my Ubuntu server from my macbook client through ssh.
Port 22 is open and the server is not behind a router.

I've run `sudo tcpdump -i any port 22 -n -Q inout`
The request is reaching the server according to the log at the end of the post:

After a while, on the client side, I get the following message:

> ssh_dispath_run_fatal: Connection to IP 50.XX.XXX.53 port 22: Operation timed out

Here's the log from tcpdump:

```
12:04:23.146323 IP 50.XX.XXX.53.22 > 50.XX.XXX.181.54440: Flags [P.], seq 1:1098, ack 22, win 509, options [nop,nop,TS val 3036629512 ecr 291479258], length 1097

12:04:23.610318 IP 50.XX.XXX.53.22 > 50.XX.XXX.181.54440: Flags [P.], seq 1:1098, ack 22, win 509, options [nop,nop,TS val 3036629976 ecr 291479258], length 1097

12:04:24.538367 IP 50.XX.XXX.53.22 > 50.XX.XXX.181.54440: Flags [P.], seq 1:1098, ack 22, win 509, options [nop,nop,TS val 3036630904 ecr 291479258], length 1097
12:04:26.394273 IP 50.XX.XXX.53.22 > 50.XX.XXX.18*1.54440: Flags [P.], seq 1:1098, ack 22, win 509, options [nop,nop,TS val 3036632760 ecr 291479258], length 1097
12:04:30.170283 IP 50.XX.XXX.53.22 > 50.XX.XXX.181.54440: Flags [P.], seq 1:1098, ack 22, win 509, options [nop,nop,TS val 3036636536 ecr 291479258], length 1097
12:04:37.594251 IP 50.XX.XXX.53.22 > 50.XX.XXX.181.54440: Flags [P.], seq 1:1098, ack 22, win 509, options [nop,nop,TS val 3036643960 ecr 291479258], length 1097
```

firewall status:

```
~$ sudo ufw status
Status: active
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
3309                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
3306                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
3306/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
3309 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
3306 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
3306/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

SSH Server Status:

```
~$ sudo service ssh status
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: e>
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-12-15 10:12:35 PST; 2 days ago
       Docs: man:sshd(8)
             man:sshd_config(5)
   Main PID: 1095 (sshd)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 14301)
     Memory: 10.8M
     CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
             ├─ 1095 sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 1 of 10-100 startups
             ├─35862 sshd: [accepted]
             └─35863 sshd: [net]

Dec 17 12:09:47 dell sshd[35481]: Received disconnect from 221.131.165.119 port 64023:11:  [preauth]
Dec 17 12:09:47 dell sshd[35481]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 221.131.165.119 port 64023 [preauth]
Dec 17 12:11:10 dell sshd[35604]: Unable to negotiate with 112.85.42.110 port 18630: no matching key exchange method found. Their >
Dec 17 12:12:57 dell sshd[35651]: Received disconnect from 221.181.185.18 port 33792:11:  [preauth]
Dec 17 12:12:57 dell sshd[35651]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 221.181.185.18 port 33792 [preauth]
Dec 17 12:15:21 dell sshd[35753]: Unable to negotiate with 218.92.0.165 port 9913: no matching key exchange method found. Their of>
Dec 17 12:15:37 dell sshd[35765]: Received disconnect from 222.187.238.87 port 42340:11:  [preauth]
Dec 17 12:15:37 dell sshd[35765]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 222.187.238.87 port 42340 [preauth]
Dec 17 12:18:32 dell sshd[35879]: Received disconnect from 222.187.232.73 port 34770:11:  [preauth]
Dec 17 12:18:32 dell sshd[35879]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 222.187.232.73 port 34770 [preauth]
~*
```

---

➜ So I've run: `ssh augusto@server.mydomain.ca -vvv`

```
OpenSSH_8.4p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1h  22 Sep 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/augusto/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/augusto/.ssh/config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: /Users/augusto/.ssh/config line 24: Ignored unknown option "usekeychain"
debug1: Reading configuration data /usr/local/etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/Users/augusto/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/Users/augusto/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "server.mydomian.ca" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to server.mydomian.ca [50.68.XXX.53] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/augusto/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/augusto/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to server.mydomain.ca:22 as 'augusto'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/augusto/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to 50.68.XXX.53 port 22: Operation timed out
```

---

The server is using a public ip, and the mac client is behind a router.

Comment: User `root` is disabled by default on Ubuntu

Comment: if you enabled `root` account (which we never suggest to have enabled it), then post output of `ssh username@yourUbuntuServer -vvv` into your question please. click to **[edit]**

Comment: It looks like you are receiving some ssh traffic from public IP addresses. How many interfaces does your machine have? Is that mac client on a different LAN to these? Is it connecting via the internet, or via local LAN. The 50.x.x.x IP addresses are in the public IP range. Perhaps provide a diagram of your network setup.

Comment: Just wanted to mention, I've been getting hit by similar IPs on my machine on the cloud.

Comment: In the server try to SSH to the 127.0.0.1 to exclude issues with client-server communication. Use `-vvv` parameter and let's see if it will go past the `expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY` msg.